# What is the time complexity of this nested loop?

Tags: time-complexity

I stumbled upon a loop for which I am not sure what the time complexity is. It is the following loop:

```
for(i = 1; i <= n^2; i++){
   for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      //some elementary operation
   }
}
```

I would have argued that the outer for-loop runs in n^2 and the inner for loop would also run in n^2 as for every iteration of the outer-loop we do n^2 - (n^2 - 1), n^2 - (n^2 - 2),..., n^2. Am I totally going in the wrong direction here?

So the time complexity would be in n^4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of operation will be :

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + n²
```

Which is equal to (n² * (n² - 1)) / 2.

The Big O notation is O(n^4). You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple arithmetic progression happening here.

Every new iteration is bigger by 1.

Outer loop will do n^2 operations which will result for following sequence:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n + ... + n^2 = n^2 (n^2+1) / 2 = O(n^4)
```